# Is socketcluster redundant when using cluster js in a node js app?

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

Let's say I am trying to scale my app for over 200k+ socket connection in a node js app, how do I go about this. I have been doing a lot of research and was thinking about:
-application layer
-socket.io layer
-load balancer

This was after I read a socket.io benchmark testing [article](http://drewww.github.io/socket.io-benchmarking/) but stumbled upon socketcluster afterwards! I have also thought about using socket.io + redis and increasing heroku dyno's, not sure how much this will increase socket.io scalability.

My question now is wouldn't cluster js already run multiple instances of the node js server with socket.io on all cores available? If so why would you need socketcluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io requires sticky load balancing which makes your app more vulnerable to DoS attacks (with sticky load balancing, a malicious user could target specific workers and crash them one at a time). Also, sticky load balancing can lead to uneven distribution of traffic across workers when you have to handle users who are behind a corporate proxy.

Unlike SocketCluster, Socket.io does not support pub/sub which makes it difficult to communicate between users who are connected to different workers/hosts.